ES futures exchange with CMEGROUP_DOM Depth of Market (Level 2)
I am looking at quote data from ES contracts on NinjaTrader using the CMEGROUP_DOM data source, and trying to understand the events of add/update/remove of quotes and ordering.
The below simple case makes sense and is as i expect, line is added, updated then removed:
Sequence,Symbol,Exchange,Time,Type,Operation,Price,Volume,Position,MarketMaker
ES 06-24,Globex,2024-04-01T20:21:35.0190000,Ask,Add,5290,122,2,
ES 06-24,Globex,2024-04-01T20:21:35.2770000,Ask,Update,5290,128,2,3
ES 06-24,Globex,2024-04-01T20:21:35.3860000,Ask,Update,5290,127,2,3
ES 06-24,Globex,2024-04-01T20:21:35.4700000,Ask,Update,5290,112,2,3
ES 06-24,Globex,2024-04-01T20:21:35.8090000,Ask,Remove,0,0,2,3

But I am also seeing cases within the same stream where removes are happening, without any corresponding add prior:

Questions please as I rule out any coding issues during my capture (I dump direct to a file currently for this analysis, above screenshot is filtered for positions 0,1,2 of ask side):

Why are there multiple removes performed but none added prior?
Can market makers share the same position on the ladder (this makes
total sense, but not what i am seeing in the data)?
Is the market maker important, is this what is confusing me here?
Pointers for books or links to understand the stream in more detail.

Thanks in advance.

Could you clarify: (1) What timezone are the timestamps in? (2) Are those prices roll-adjusted or unadjusted?

Thanks for the reply @databento. It is the local machine time as given from NinjaTrader, I will do some further processing to make it exchange time, in the excel screenshot it’s 30 minutes into the US market open so very active at that time. The prices are direct from the contract and unadjusted

I see. The reason I'm asking is that because I couldn't find these prices at any of the times (UTC, Eastern, Central) on the raw exchange data. Separately, CME gives order IDs in their MBO/L3 data, but not MPID, so you shouldn't be able to identify market makers. I think you should ask NinjaTrader Support for help on this.

Many thanks. They say they don’t know it comes direct from the data provider. Could you kindly let me know the data supplier where you get your futures contract data from? I would have a budget of 250 usd per month for NQ and ES tick and order book data (around spot as it updates)

:) We are an official supplier and primary source of CME data ourselves.
https://databento.com
https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/license-data/licensed-market-data-distributors.html
